# If iI have a capacitor connected to a battery can the negative charge be sent to an insulated object

Tags: electrons, charge, capacitance

If I have a capacitor permanently connected to a battery, that is lets say setting in a plastic bowl, and then run a wire from the negative of the battery to a non grounded object, say a metal can that is not grounded. Will the metal can take in electrons and be negatively charged to any degree? And what would happen if I did this and had the can grounded to earth. Would it still take on the same amount of electrons from the battery, or more or less?

Answer (score -1):

I can't understand your question thoroughly.

But if you connect the negative terminal of the battery to any conducting body like a metal can, then there will be a flow of charge till the potential of the negative terminal and the metal are equal because the metal body and the negative terminal are a single conducting body and a conducting body has a equipotential.